# InvalidRequestError Must provide an engine ( gpt 4 azure open ai Langchain python)

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api, langchain, azure-openai

I'm trying to integrate gpt 4 azure open ai with Langchain but when i try to use it inside ConversationalRetrievalChain it is throwing some error

```
raise error.InvalidRequestError(\\n *~* 
openai.error.InvalidRequestError: Must provide an \'engine\' or
 \'deployment_id\' parameter to create a <class 
\'openai.api_resources.chat_completion.ChatCompletion\
```

but if i run standalone openai instance with azure openai config it is working, I'm confused whether langchain supports gpt 4 or am I missing anything

Comment: Please include more context, particularly the code  and the full traceback error.

Comment: I got the same error message when using index.query(). I am not sure if "deployment_id / engine" is a must for Azure OpenAI as I don't need it for OpenAI. Here is my code:


`index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex.load_from_disk('index.json')`
`response = index.query(input_text)`